# When one check column is selected how to make the user not to select other check columns in EXTJS grid panel

Tags: extjs, extjs5, gridpanel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM2VG.png)I have a grid panel which includes 4 check columns.

Three of the columns need to act like radio options; when the user checks one column they should not be able to check the other two columns.

The fourth column should be independent and unaffected by the other three.

I am using ExtJs version 5.1

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyGridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mygridpanel',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.MyGridPanelViewModel',
        'MyApp.view.MyGridPanelViewController',
        'Ext.grid.column.Check',
        'Ext.view.Table'
    ],

    controller: 'mygridpanel',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'mygridpanel'
    },
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    title: 'My Grid Panel',

    columns: [
        {
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'string',
            text: 'String'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'number',
            text: 'Number',
            listeners: {
                checkchange: 'onCheckcolumnCheckChange'
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'date',
            text: 'Date'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'bool',
            text: 'Boolean'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can disable, and what you probably mean is uncheck?

If so you seem to be half way there, I would use listeners on your check columns e.g.

See it in action here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qpr

```
onCheckcolumnCheckChange:function(column,rowIndex,checked,record){
    var gridHeader = column.up();
    gridHeader.items.each(function(col){
        if(checked && col.xtype==='checkcolumn'&&col!==column){
            record.set(col.dataIndex,false);
        }
    })
}
```

If you want to only do this to certain check columns you can always check the dataIndex aswell:

```
onCheckcolumnCheckChange:function(column,rowIndex,checked,record){
    var gridHeader = column.up();
    gridHeader.items.each(function(col){
        if(checked && checked.dataIndex!='other' && col.xtype==='checkcolumn'&&col!==column){
            record.set(col.dataIndex,false);
        }
    })
}
```

A nicer way to do this (particularly if you want have several additional check columns that are not unset when others are checked) would be to add a custom property to your columns and then check this.

```
{
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'date',
    text: 'Date',
    checkgroup: 'threecols',
    listeners: {
        checkchange: 'onCheckcolumnCheckChange'
    }
},
```

Note `checkgroup` is not a standard config/property - but you can set custom properties this way (as long as they don't clash with real ones)

Then in your `onCheckcolumnCheckChange` method you can check this:

```
if (checked && col.checkgroup && col.checkgroup === column.checkgroup && col.xtype === 'checkcolumn' && col !== column) {
    record.set(col.dataIndex, false);
}
```

An additional bonus of this approach would make it easy to have multiple sets of checkboxes, where you set different 'checkgroup' values.

Comment: Thank you Theo. What if i want to keep one of the check column remain same and the user have to select only from one from the rest 3 check columns. Can you help me here

Comment: In the example you gave I want to keep the String check column to remain unchanged.(user can check and uncheck this column not dependent on the rest three) . the user should be able to select only one column from Number, Date and Boolean check columns.

Comment: Thanks! !! Theo but again new issue i m writing the listener in my view controller I get an error Type error: record is null. I am writing my listener event in view controller.

Comment: Ext.define('Wxample.view.exampleViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.examplepanel',
onCheckcolumnCheckChange:function(column,rowIndex,checked,record){

     var gridHeader = column.up();
    var record = me.getViewModel().get('record');//i think i am doing something wrong here
        gridHeader.items.each(function(col){
         console.log(col);
            if(checked && col.xtype==='checkcolumn'&&col!==column &&col.dataIndex!=='taxYesNo'){ 
               record.set(col.dataIndex,false);
            } })  } });

Comment: onCheckcolumnCheckChange gets passed record so you should not need to get it from anywhere, please create a fiddle so I can see the code better

Comment: It works fine with fiddle but in my actual project if I am not passing the record it says record.set is not a function and if I set the record as var record = me.getViewModel().get('record'); It gives me record is null. Is it something because I have a store and a webservice passing me the data. Can you please help me.https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qug

Comment: Please see the attached image in the question. When I check my console record is giving me object instead of constructor So i guess I am making mistake while passing the record.

Comment: This fiddle consists my actual files https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qul

Comment: OK I have got this working - but it is far beyond the scope of the Q&A nature of stackoverflow. Here is the fixed fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qv7 - **But please review my changes and comments by looking at the difference; I don't think its great to just fix code for people without explaining what has been changed.** you can see the difference here: https://www.diffchecker.com/HnNygjHs  - Please be sure to accept my answer/upvote (if you are happy I answered your original question)

Comment: Thanks a ton Theo can you please take a look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587253/binding-grid-and-form-extjs-6